# Magento 2 Cart Memory Exhaustion issue, with customer

Tags: magento2, php, memory, memory-leak

Running Magento 2.1.10 CE, with multiple stores.

Client requires login to access the site

Running into an issue where one of the client is having a problem with cart. 
They have added 53 products in their cart, but when they try to update the cart, by adding a new item or editing quantity of an existing, The allowed memory gets exhausted. No matter how much i increase the memory size (now 3GB), it still get exhausted, pointing to a memory leak. This also happens on checkout page. (before showing the payment methods)

I created a test user account on the site and replicated the above user cart. For this user, i have no issues, i can add more items, update quantities for already added ones, and even complete the checkout.

I have checked the values for the both customers, and they are pretty much similar apart from unique values such as email etc

I am currently running out of idea how to debug it further. 
I tried writing a script to modify the cart, but i still get memory issue for that particular user

The site is setup on an amazon server, using a combination of redis, varnish, setup on nginx

Comment: I've run into the same problem. One customer with 8 items in the shopping cart, 9 items in the wishlist, 3 items in the last order and 4 items in the recently viewed. Nothing I would say is out of the ordinary, but runs out a 8GB. I'll keep looking to see if I can find the cause.

Comment: Oh in Magento 2 there's a file in the root directory ".user.ini" that resets the memory limit locally to 756M, even if you set the memory to 2048M in the php.ini file.